# FB.login appears behind page in IE 9

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-9, facebook-javascript-sdk

We're ready to deploy a Facebook app, where users are able to search for one of their friends and select this friend.

When clicking on the input-tag, I invoke FB.login() and get necessary permissions. It works on all browsers but the customer experince a weird problem (which I cannot reproduce).

When clicking on the input-tag, the permission dialog from Facebook appears behind the website (does not popup in front), giving the impression that something failed. The customer can find it when hovering the combined windows for IE but this is not intuitive.

She is using IE9 (32bit) on Win7 - same as me and other testers (except for being emulated 32bit). She mentioned it has worked as expected previously but after I've tested through all the codebase, I still cant find a solution.

Comment: Came a bit further. Seems this is only reproducible when using documentmode 9 and browserwindow is maximized. Using any other IE version or making it float (or even fullscreen) makes it work. I am unable to reproduce it, only the PCs in the customers firm can reproduce this. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was only happening for the PCs in the Active Directory farm. Once they chose to update all IEs, the problem disappeared.